# rename an file on local disk using PHP or Javascript

Tags: php

I have a scenario in which user is prompted for selecting a file from local disk (an image). Upon selection, this image is shown in browser (without uploading). After seeing the image user inputs a number in CN No field. Upon submit I want to rename the file on local disk with the number input by user. Is there some way to do this in code using PHP or Javascript?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function preview_image(event) 
{
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function()
 {
  var output = document.getElementById('output_image');
  output.src = reader.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
 Select File: <input type="file" accept="image/*"     onchange="preview_image(event)"> <br>
 Enter CN No. <input type="number" id="cnno" name="cnno"> <br>
 <input id="sbt" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" accesskey="u">     <br>
</form>

 <img id="output_image" style="width: 400px"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Local disk as in the client's disk or the server's disk?

Comment: No, that would be a huge security breach in JavaScript.

Comment: You cannot (should not be able) to mess with my disk using code I receive from the internet, Otherwise there woudl just be a billion bot out here and the internet would be useless

Comment: You could just download the selected file which is renamed, dont need to upload.

Comment: @Devon "this image is shown in browser (**without uploading**)"

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yeah but it also says rename after submit and is tagged php which is server-side, so it's a bit confusing.

Comment: Infact around 2000 images are received per day which contain unique numbers on these, and I want to identify these image files with the unique number as part of filename. But do not want to upload these on server because it would take too much space on server. If I upload these on server and download a copy with new name (and then delete from server), original files would remain on local machine and it would be hectic for user to track which files have been processed and which have not been. If have any other solution, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this, presuming downloading the file is ok.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  var img;

  function preview_image(elm) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(event) {
     img = event.target.result
     document.getElementById("image_preview").src = img;
   };
   reader.readAsDataURL(elm.files[0]);
  }

  function download() {
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', img)
    element.setAttribute('download', document.getElementById("cnno").value+'.png');

    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
  }
  </script>
</head>
<body>

Select File: <input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="preview_image(this)"> <br>
Enter CN No. <input type="number" id="cnno" name="cnno"> <br>
<input id="sbt" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" accesskey="u" onclick="download()"><br>

<img id="image_preview" style="width: 400px"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can it download the file to location from where file was selected ?

Comment: No, that's again up to the user or defined download location, essentially what your trying to do cant be done, my answer is as close as you get to what you want, anything closer would be a security risk. e.g [drive-by-downloads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drive-by_download) so the browser prevents writing to the users files and downloading to specific locations, and the user specifically has to trigger the download etc

Comment: Though it does seem like an odd request as the user simply need rename the file, your trying to script something which is a basic computing task. (sidenote, if you were using electron its possible to do what you quiet easily)

Comment: Yes it is nearest. Thanks for help.Yet I have to do some validation and event recording in database.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var file = document.GetElementById('fileupload1');
var blob = file.files[0].slice(0, -1, 'image/png'); 
newFile = new File([blob], 'name.png', {type: 'image/png'});
```

But its only for image rename.